# What fuel would a Bell Huey helicopter use in 1964?

Tags: helicopter, fuel, bell-uh-1

What type fuel would a Bell Huey have used in 1964? If that matters, let's say for a medical evacuation situation

Comment: Uh...what it normally uses.

Answer (score 7):

In 1964, the Huey would use JP-4 or JP-5 .

When fitted with models T53-L-5 or T53-L9, the Huey would burn JP-4. 
With engine variety engine T53-L11 it would burn either JP-4 or JP-5. The JP-5 type fuel was mainly used for Navy operations.